# Add data to a unique, required column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm looking for the preferred way, and unique column to an existing table.  I also want to add a unique index to the table.  Before adding the index though, I obviously need to add data to the column to prevent the index creation from failing.

Here is the situation:

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, null: false

    # Need Data here! And don't want to do something like this:
    # User.each { |u| u.update_attribute(:username, u.email }

    add_index  :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

I know using ruby code to populate the data is possible, there are lots of examples of that, but I keep reading that it isn't such a good idea.  Are there any options other than something similar to the above?

Comment: most database engines allow to add an auto increment field which will automatically filled in with auto incremented values with the alter table statement. That may (or may not) be a solution for you

Comment: Probably not a great solution for a string based username column

Comment: Using default value? `add_column :users, :username, :string, null: false, default: "Generic Username"`

Comment: That'll break the unique index.

Comment: It's a better idea to populate data with rake task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would the following work for your situation?

```
class AddUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :username, :string, null: true

    execute("UPDATE users SET username = email")
    change_column :users, :username, :string, null: false

    add_index  :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is what I'll go with, combined with the suggestion above to use rake tasks.  Thanks for the response!